# why atomic operation is faster using separate threads?

Tags: memory, go, concurrency, cpu, cpu-cache

I have two pieces of code and there are 32 cores on my desktop.

Code A uses 32 threads and does the following thing,

1) write values to some random locations in memory
2) atomically add a value to a global variable.

Code B uses 16 threads to write values to random locations and uses another 16 threads to atomically add a value to a global variable.

I was wondering why code B is faster in terms of how many atomic operation executed per second to the global variable.

Here is code A

```
var a uint64 = 0

const N = 10 * 1024 * 1024

var data [N]uint64

func main() {

    for i := 0; i < 32; i ++ {
        go func(id int) {
            source := rand.NewSource(int64(id))
            local_rand := rand.New(source)
            for {
                atomic.AddUint64(&a, uint64(1))
                data[local_rand.Int31n(N)] = uint64(1)
            }
        }(i)

    }

    var b uint64 = 0

    for {
        c := atomic.LoadUint64(&a)

        fmt.Println(c - b)
        b = c
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }

}
```

Here is code B

```
var a uint64 = 0

const N = 10 * 1024 * 1024

var data [N]uint64

func main() {

    for i := 0; i < 16; i ++ {
        go func(id int) {
            source := rand.NewSource(int64(id))
            local_rand := rand.New(source)
            for {
                data[local_rand.Int31n(N)] = uint64(1)
            }
        }(i)

    }
    for i := 0; i < 16; i++ {

        go func() {
            for {
                atomic.AddUint64(&a, uint64(1))
            }

        }()
    }
    var b uint64 = 0

    for {
        c := atomic.LoadUint64(&a)

        fmt.Println(c - b)
        b = c
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Atomic operations are expensive. In order to maintain atomicity, you need to ensure mutually exclusive execution for that block of code. Usually this is achieved using instructions like load-linked, store-conditional etc. In your code A, you have 32 atomic operations, but in code B, you only got 16. Less atomic work, reduced execution time!

As an experiment, try changing order of the atomic operations with the memory operation in your code A.( Just do memory first and atomic afterwards). You should see a reduction in execution time.

Comment: I don't think changing the number of threads to 16 in code A improves the performance.

Comment: I don't see any difference from what you proposed. Memory first then atomics. Did I miss anything?

Comment: If you have all threads doing atomic first, they all will contend for the lock. If you have memory first, they all will do memory first, however due what's being cached or not, memory operation will complete at different times. This means atomic operations will start at different times. So you will not have the same contention you had earlier. So I was expecting less execution time. May be all your data is cached, not doing what I was expecting.. anyway just a theory that crossed my mind.

Comment: You could try another experiment. Spawn 32 threads, make odd ones do the memory and even ones do the atomic. Now you should see the same time as code B.

Comment: i mean the two operations are in a for loop. Does the order really matter? I don't have access to my laptop so I can not try what you said.